# My window.clear() function isnt working, cant clear window

Tags: python, pyglet

I wrote a code which draws a cube in a window in python using pyglet, and on certain key presses i move the cube a bit, but the previous cube stays there. So after N key presses i have N+1 cube in a window, but i should have only one. What am I doing wrong? I have my code which looks like this:

```
class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

 def __init__(self, width, height):
    super(Window, self).__init__(width=width, height=height)

 def on_draw(self):
    self.clear()
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    # just some drawing tools glvertex2f etc.
        glEnd()

 def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
    self.clear()
    if symbol == key.SPACE: etc. etc.
```

'''

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, __Complete, and Verifiable__ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: out of curiosity, what happens if you add `self.flip()` at the end of `on_draw()`? Also, don't call `self.clear()` on `on_key_press`. You probably also need to do something that actually triggers a `on_draw` (like a trigger or something, add a print() and it probably only prints once)